# jQueryUI - draggable with a separate click to drop

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I've implemented drag and drop OK with jQueryUI draggable and droppable.

For the less savvy users, I'd like to also offer a visible "move" button. When they click this button, the element would be picked up, and when they click again on a drop target, it's dropped. So the same as drag and drop, but started with one click and dropped with another.

I know it would be possible to do this with separate code, but I'd rather not reinvent everything for a slight variation. Is there a way to get jQueryUI to do this?

The only thing I found is calling the trigger method of the draggable, but you have to pass a mousedown event...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598212/movable-div-without-jquery-ui/8598380#8598380). If you change it so instead of

```
$("#headerDiv")
  .mousedown(function(event) {
    x = event.pageX;
    y = event.pageY;
    $(this).parent().addClass('movable');
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('movable');
  });
```

bind to `click` and implement a toggling mechanism to decide if you are beginning the drag (`mousedown` equivalent) or ending the drag (`mouseup` equivalent) you should be most of the way there.

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand you right. But I don't see how this allows me to reuse the jQueryUI drag-drop support - I would be just doing a whole new mechanism...

Comment: It turns out there are too many draggable items to perform well; so the setup time for jQueryUI draggable on them all is prohibitive on IE8 and Chrome. Instead I'm changing to only the explicit "move" button mechanism, so doing something like what you guys discuss. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I would use .animate to animate the object to its target. I have done this before with a game. For example you could specify top and left coordinates for the element to move to onClick of the button.